# How to insert VARIANT data into a Snowflake table?

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (i int PRIMARY KEY, j variant);
```

I'm trying to insert some JSON object into the table, e.g.

```sql
INSERT INTO t (i, j) VALUES (1, object_construct('a', 1));
```

However, that fails with:

> SQL Error [2014] [22000]: SQL compilation error:
> Invalid expression [OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('a', 1)] in VALUES clause

I can work around the problem with this:

```sql
INSERT INTO t (i, j) VALUES (1, null);
UPDATE t SET j = object_construct('a', 1) WHERE i = 1;
```

Why can't I use `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT` in an `INSERT` statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[INSERT INTO ... VALUES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert#usage-notes):

> **Some expressions cannot be specified in the VALUES clause.** As an alternative, specify the expression in a query clause. For example, you can replace:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO table1 (ID, varchar1, variant1)
> VALUES (4, 'Fourier', PARSE_JSON('{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }'));
> ```
>
> with:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO table1 (ID, varchar1, variant1)
> SELECT 4, 'Fourier', PARSE_JSON('{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" }');
> ```

---

[VALUES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/values):

> ```
> <expr>
> ```
>
> **Each expression must be a constant, or an expression that can be evaluated as a constant during compilation of the SQL statement.**
>
> Most simple arithmetic expressions and string functions can be evaluated at compile time, **but most other expressions cannot.**

---

Same applies to both `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT` and [OBJECT curly braces](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured#label-object-constant) :

```
INSERT INTO t (i, j) SELECT 1, {'a', 1};
```

Answer (score 1):

[The manual suggests using `INSERT .. SELECT`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured#example-of-inserting-a-variant):

> To insert `VARIANT` data directly, use IIS (`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`).

I.e. this works:

```sql
INSERT INTO t (i, j) SELECT 1, object_construct('a', 1);
```

However, it does not offer any explanation with respect to the limitation, or why this particular workaround is needed.

Comment: Just a sidenote: `object_construct('a', 1)` could be further simplified with curly braces syntax `SELECT {'a':1}`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: Interesting syntax sugar. But it's just that. Trying `INSERT INTO t (i, j) VALUES (1, {'a': 1});` results in the same error: `Invalid expression [OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('a', 1)] in VALUES clause`