# Change value in variant type column in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant

I have a table in Snowflake with two columns. The first column named Key with type varchar, and the second column named Value with type Variant.

```
Key           | Value                      |
SampleKeyName | "2023-08-15 12:50:01.000"  |
```

How can I change the value in the Value column? Or add new one?

i have tried

```sql
INSERT INTO DATABASE ("Key", "Value") VALUES (
  'DateName',
   TO_VARIANT ('2023-08-15 12:00:00.000')
);
```

and so on

```sql
PARSE_JSON('{"date": "2023-08-15 12:00:00.000"}')
TO_VARIANT(PARSE_JSON('{"date": "2023-08-15 12:00:00.000"}'))
TO_VARIANT('{"date": "2023-08-15 12:00:00.000"}')
TO_VARIANT('2023-08-15 12:50:01.000')
TO_VARIANT('{"2023-08-15 12:50:01.000"}')
TO_VARIANT(TO_VARCHAR('2023-08-15 12:50:01.000'::TIMESTAMP_NTZ))
```

but it still return me Invalid expression.

Comment: [How to insert VARIANT data into a Snowflake table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75510128/5070879)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert VARIANT data into a Snowflake table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75507894/how-to-insert-variant-data-into-a-snowflake-table)

Comment: Please paste the exact error message. At least one of your trials should work, so maybe this error has some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, this is what worked for me:

```
'2023-08-15 12:50:01.000'::VARCHAR
```